# multivariable maxima and minima

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

---

I try to calculate minma and maxima in $ x^2 + y^2 -12x+16y = z$ for the boundary $x^2+y^2<=25$ however I keep getting only$ (6,-8)$ as a possible point when there are other two answers . how do I do this?

Comment: Firstly, $6^2+(-8)^2 > 25$. A typo ?  Secondly, have you tried to apply the KKT-conditions ?

Comment: 6,-8 is my answer not offical one....whats kkt?

Comment: Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions

Comment: not my course level probably

Comment: Probably ? What does your lecture manusscript tells you ?

Comment: I am utterly certain  Karush-Kuhn-Tucker is never mentioned

Comment: Then I have no idea. Although is has not been mentioned in the course it can be mentioned in your lecture manuscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers because it looks like you need the maximum and the minimum. (6, -8) does not work because is violates your condition $x^2+y^2<=25$. I assume you got this by calculating the derivative and setting it equal to zero. If you investigate the function in Wolfram Mathematica you will see our points then must lie on the circle. Clearly the absolute minimum which you calculated to be in the center of the dark red circle on the contour plots does not meet your constraint. In this case the green dot is your min and the red dot is your max.

[image: This is your function]

[image: This is the min with your constraint]

[image: This is the max with your constraint]

To get to the solution mathematically we need to write the equation as:

$$L = x^2+y^2-12x+16y+\lambda(x^2+y^2-25)$$

Next we formulate the conditions:

$$x^2+y^2<=25$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2x-12+2\lambda x=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} =2y+16+2\lambda y=0$$
$$\lambda (x^2+y^2-25)=0$$
$$\lambda >=0$$

Solving this system will yield the points you want at (-3, 4) and (3, -4). For example say we take $\lambda = 0$ then we will get the point (6, -8) but this violates the first condition so $\lambda > 0$. With lambda greater than zero we can reduce the system to:
$$x^2+y^2=25$$ (on the circle boundary)
$$2x-12+2 \lambda x = 0$$
$$2y+16+2 \lambda y = 0$$

The solution of this will yield your answers.

Comment: on point, thanks!